# How to put a Fontawesome icon on a DataTable button? - Angular

Tags: angular, datatables, angular-cli, font-awesome

I'm using [angular-fontawesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome) and [datatables](http://datatables.net) and I want to create a button in the table, but instead of text I want to place an icon using [fontawesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome). I have the following code:

```js
this.dtOptions = {
    //...
    buttons: [
        //...
        {
            extend: 'pdf',
            text: '<fa-icon [icon]="faDownload"></fa-icon>'
        }
    ]           
};
```

I know that I will not load the component of the icon in this way, but is there a way to do it without having to use the fontawesome css?

Comment: you want to place that button in each row of table?

Comment: No, those buttons would go up the table, those buttons are an extension of datatable

Comment: You want do it without having to use the fontawesome css or what? Can you explain the exact problem?

Comment: I think it will not work this way. Angular will not render fa-icon component after innerHtml alike action called by datatables.

Comment: @TarunLalwani I want to pre-compile an icon using https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome and upload it to a certain part of my webpage through TypeScript

Answer (score 7):

I think the only option is to use html. [API](https://datatables.net/reference/option/buttons.buttons.text) says that you can use html in `text` property of button config. For example you can use something like this:
`<i class="fas fa-download"></i>`

Answer (score 7):

As long as you have fontawesome loaded you can just manipulate the `className` property. I will recommend you to reset the default button layout setup through the `dom` property as well. As other points out, do not mix angular (+2) directives with that part of the code. It will probably not work (I am into angular1, but its the same deal) and really not necessary anyway. Here is an example :

```js
buttons: {
  //reset class and change the rendered tag 
  //from <button> to <i>
  dom: {
    button: {
      tag: 'i',
      className: ''
    }
  },
  //since we now have completely unstyled icons add
  //some space between them trough a .custom-btn class
  buttons: [
   {
     titleAttr: 'Download as PDF',
     extend: 'pdfHtml5',
     className: 'custom-btn fa fa-file-pdf-o',
     text: ''
   },
   {
     titleAttr: 'Download as Excel',     
     extend: 'excelHtml5',
     className: 'custom-btn fa fa-file-excel-o',
     text: ''
   },
   {
     titleAttr: 'Download as CSV',     
     extend: 'csvHtml5',
     className: 'custom-btn fa fa-file-text-o',
     text: ''
   },
   {
     titleAttr: 'Print',     
     extend: 'print',
     className: 'custom-btn fa fa-print',
     text: ''
   }
 ]
}
```

```css
.custom-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/r47ao4h3/**

I do not have a working plunkr using DT and Angular2 at hand, but can produce an Angular1 example if you want. For all it is the same deal, there is no difference.

Comment: Very good response, but it's not what I'm looking for.
I know there is a way to pre-compile a component, but I do not know how it works.

Comment: @SamirLlorente, OK! As mentioned I only know angularjs in depth, in that you could use `$compile` for example if you need to inject directives to rows or columns, but even in angularjs there is no way to compile the content of the buttons library. Still, it is a pure oldschool jQuery library and the buttons plugin is an extension of that library that does most things under the hood. I am afraid it simply is not possible to use directives along with buttons.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use angular component instead of raw html, then you will have to pre-render angular component somewhere in a hidden container (i.e. create `fa-icon` component dynamically using component factory) and then manually copy rendered html to button configuration. This is far more complicated process with little benefits.

- new angular elements will probably make slightly more simple.

Comment: How would you do it?

Comment: see https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader and https://angular.io/guide/elements

Answer (score 2):

What you can do as a simple solution is to add all your need icons in a hidden `div` and give each one an `id` so their `svg` element will be rendered and you can assign an icon to relevant button text.

[image]

```
<div id="icons" style="visibility: hidden;">
  <fa-icon id="faCoffee" [icon]="faCoffee"></fa-icon>
  <fa-icon id="faPrint" [icon]="faPrint"></fa-icon>
  <fa-icon id="faDownload" [icon]="faDownload"></fa-icon>
  <fa-icon id="faUser" [icon]="faUser"></fa-icon>
</div>
```

Assign button text to icon rendered HTML

```
buttons: [{
  text: $("#faCoffee").html()
}, {
  text: $("#faPrint").html()
}, {
  text: $("#faUser").html()
}, {
  text: $("#faDownload").html()
}]
```

Also, you can remove this temp dev and icons after your table is rendered to clean up your HTML

```
$('#example').on('init.dt', function () {
  $("#icons").remove();
});
```